# Empty list on "Where do you want to install Windows" in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-7-x64

I'm creating a virtual windows 7 enterprise 64bit on my new Macbook Pro using VirtualBox.
Following the wizard, I selected the correct operating system, allocated 512 RAM, 50GB VDI storage (dynamically allocated), and on startup I injected my ISO installer file as the CD to boot from.

Then I started my new virtual machine.
But I can't get any further then the first screen "Where do you want to install Windows". It displays an empty list and I don't get options to partition anything or make a new disk.

The VDI file is however present in the appropriate VirtualBox VMs folder on my Mac. I tried giving every file and directory in that folder all rights, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Also, when I look to my VM settings, in the Storage tab there seems to be a Controller: SATA item present, containing the Windows 7 64bit.vdi

I completely erased VirtualBox (including all settings files) using an App remover tool, reinstalled it, but still I can't get any further, it keeps displaying an empty list.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just for kicks, try removing the disk from the SATA controller and putting it on an IDE controller...

Comment: I have no idea what these controller names mean, and why VirtualBox attached it there.

Comment: IDE is `Integrated Drive Electronics` and SATA is `Serial Advanced Technology Attachment` - which is newer than IDE. They are just different generations of disk interfaces. Windows hasn't always been that good at working out SATA controllers and sometimes you need to insert a `Driver Disk` during installation for it to know how to talk to such things. Windows is more likely to be able to find the older IDE drives and as they are only simulated in Virtual Box anyway, it doesn't really matter that much which you choose.